# Как выполнить PHP скрипт, занимающий более 5 минут на обработку

Tags: php, ajax, api, curl

Есть php-скрипт, который возвращает информацию о файле. Работает через api одного сайта. Первое, что нужно, это отправить файл на сервер через POST. В ответе будет json строка, содержащая id задачи:

```
$url = "https://site.com/api/file/upload";

$path = "your_file_path_here";
$file = new \CURLFile($path);

$params = array(
"param1" => "text",
"param2" => $file
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
'X-Auth-Token: Your Token Here'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

curl_close($ch);
```

Далее я делаю GET запрос, используя данный id, чтобы получить интересующую информацию о файле:

```
$url = "https://site.com/api/file/result/".$result["data"]["id"];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"X-Auth-Token: Your Token Here"
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

curl_close($ch);
```

Однако проблема заключается в том, что информация на сервере обрабатывается не сразу. И результат приходит не полный. Максимальное время, которое требуется для получения всех результатов 5 минут.

Сначала я использовал простую форму, с `action=""` на страницу php, где был код, который представлен выше. Я пробовал делать цикл `while`, который проверял не готов ли результат и делал задержку на минуту. Макс. кол-во итераций было задано 6, но сервер через некоторое время давал ошибку:

> timeout. set_time_limit

```
$max_iterations = 6;
$current_iteration = 0;
$retrieve_results = true;

while($retrieve_results){
    $objects= $result["data"];
    $scanned_count = 0;
    foreach($objectsas $object){
        if($object["status"] === "true"){
            $count++;
        }
    }

    if($count === count($objects)){
        exit;
    }

    $current_iteration++;
    if($current_iteration === $max_iterations){
        $retrieve_results = false;
        exit;
    }
    sleep(60);
}
```

Далее решил попробовать загрузку файла через ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: formdata,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Однако ровно через 1 минуту скрипт сбрасывается, так и не дождавшись ответа.

Без цикла `while` все работает, но результат, который нужен не полный, как я уже писал выше

Какие есть варианты решения проблемы? Как вариант хотел попробовать сделать запись в базу данных с последующим обновлением страницы с помощью js, если данные были обновлены, но пока даже не знаю как это все реализовать

Answer (score 0):

Навскидку есть 2 пути решения задачи.

1. Если пользователь по-любому должен дождаться какого-либо ответа на странице, то вариант с JS более подходит. Единственное что, потребуется установить обработчик на событие "покидания страницы", чтобы переспросить пользователя, уверен ли он, что не хочет дождаться результатов обработки файла. Учтите только, что Вы в ajax-запросе не установили хедеры запроса (в PHP-коде Вы их установили!). После этого запроса вешаете на таймер проверку состояния обработчика с контролем времени, прошедшего после загрузки файла, и "в путь". Поскольку я JS не особо люблю, код не привожу, он не сложный, но для меня требует напряжения памяти.
2. Вариант с backend-обработкой на PHP.

2.1. Создаете в таблице запись, где хранится запись с ID загруженного файла и другой информацией о нем.

2.2. Создаете "задачу" (Job) на проверку статуса обработки, помещаете ее в очередь задач.

2.3. В фоновом режиме по крону запускаете отдельный скрипт-обработчик, который будет выполнять задания из очереди и опрашивать состояние конкретного загруженного файла. При отсутствии "ясного ответа" и непревышении лимита количества опросов можно поместить в очередь новое задание на опрос состояния этого же файла. Если ответ от АПИ получен - меняем состояние загруженного файла по его ID из п. 2.1.

2.4. Собственно на HTML-странице клиента по таймеру опрашиваете уже состояние загруженного файла из своей базы. Или не опрашиваете, а просто выводите при обновлении страницы состояние из базы по всем загруженным файлам клиента.

Похоже, что Вы не используете фреймворки и каждый велосипед изобретаете самостоятельно. Возможно, Вам поможет фрагмент документации, описывающий, например, как это работает в Laravel ([русский](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/queues), [английский](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues)).